# MSSQL: Finding all items between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sails.js, waterline

I am creating a sails.js REST-API based on data in a MSSQL-database. Each record have a start date and an end date. I want to supply a query-date and find all records that are "started", but not "ended". So conceptually I'm thinking:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
    record_start_date <= query_date
    AND
    record_end_date >= query_date
```

In Waterline/Sails it looks like this:

```
Model.find({
    record_start_date: { 'lessThanOrEqual': req.query.q + ' 00:00:00.0'},
    record_end_date: {  'greaterThanOrEqual': req.query.q + ' 23:59:00.0' }
})
```

However this only gives me records that fall between them, not *on* the start og end date.

Comment: And what's the value for 'record_end_date' for the records that are not "ended"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to swap the times inside the FIND:

```
Model.find({
    record_start_date: { 'lessThanOrEqual': req.query.q + ' 23:59:00.0'},
    record_end_date: {  'greaterThanOrEqual': req.query.q + ' 00:00:00.0' }
})
```

Consider the case where the record has start date 3/20 and end date 3/25.  If you pass query date of 3/25, the record_end_date would not satisfy the greater-than-or-equal condition if you append the '23:59' to it (as you initially did).

Comment: Thank you! Smooth sailing :)